# How do I replace Studs and bottom plate if the studs have been cut half way up the wall and removed

Tags: repair, framing

[image]

Should I put a 2X4 horizontal plate where they have been cut and then put a stud under it to a bottom plate, just like a wall. Or should I scab a 2X4 to the new stud like they said of the same one but it only had six inches cut off the stud.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to put down a bottom plate and sister the existing studs to it. Now mind you, I'm not a fourth generation carpenter so maybe some of them will chime in.

Comment: The bottom plate provides a solid nailer for the Sheetrock, sister or a plate across not much difference in my opinion, depends on how even & square the studs were cut If even and square I would build my mini wall and wedge it in easier to stand up with nails through plates then toe nail the top studs to the plate all lined up.+

Answer (score 0):

A header isn't necessary for a non-load bearing wall.

In order to screw the drywall on easily I would mend the studs. I wouldn't use a header because in order to keep from creating a weak horizontal seam you would need to create complicated mends on the edges to hold it in place.